# Missing bin folder in Nuget package

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, octopus-deploy

I am deploying asp.net web site via Octopus deploy. In TFS build definition I specified PowerShell script which pack and push Nuget package. Everything working working well except one thing: bin folder is not included in Nuget package.

When I tried to manually packing my web site into Nuget package I noticed that bin folder is included.

I supposed that something happened in TFS build process and bin folder is lost. But I cannot figure out how to solve this.

Any advice?

Comment: Check your drop folder. Is your website in there?

Comment: Thanks, I checked. There are no bin folder. Should I explicitly force TFS to create bin folder or no?

Comment: MrHinsh is right - odds are your project is a web *site* and not a web application project.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to build a Website rather than a Web Application. Websites are only supported for legacy and don't get any love in the tooling. You can:

1) manually create your website layout for packaging with a post-build PowerShell script.

2) upgrade from a Website to a Web Application project and feel the love.

To upgrade you can create a new Web Application project in VS and delete all the specifics, like aspx files or other overwrites. Then drop the left over files on top of the Website, and open it in your solution. You will have two entries, one for site and one for app. Fix up the web app errors and build...

Comment: Websites don't create binaries in the bin folder. The OP needs to switch to using a web application project - not web site.

Comment: After getting latest version from our TFS server , I found out that the Bin/resyln didnt exists , and the WEBSITE didn't compile ( due to C#6  code). So I had to copy it manually from my personal branch. but Is there any command that "re-create" the \Bin\roslyn folder ? all update-package / install-package - didn't help me.

Comment: Yes, change to a Web Application.